# While receiving JSON from azure service queue , some repeated values are getting appended after the end of json

Tags: java, json, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am facing a dilemma with my code,
My problem statement is that when I am sending JSon to Azure Service Bus through this piece of code

```
 BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(jsonStr);
```

and printing the JSON in Sender code , through

```
System.out.println("Json---"+jsonStr);
```

This is working fine.
But when I am receiving the JSON list from Queue through the same Azure Service Bus , I am able to receive it but some repeated end fields are getting appended after the JSOn list completion.
I am using this below piece of code :

```
     if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());


                    // Display the queue message.
                    System.out.print("From queue: ");
                  byte[] b = new byte[200];

                  String s = null;
                    int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                   System.out.println("numread--"+numRead);
                    while (-1 != numRead)
                    {
                        s = new String(b);
                        s = s.trim();

                        System.out.print(s);
                        numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                        //System.out.println("numread--"+numRead);
                    }
}
```

And the output I am getting with repeated fields appended at the end :

```
"oldPartNumber": null,
        "materialType": "4",
        "materialGroup": "HX",
        "bulkItemFlag": "N",
            "flexStringCollab04": null,
            "flexStringCollab05": null,
            "blockShipments": null,
            "earlyShipmentTolerance": 0,
            "overShipmentTolerance": 0.0,
            "priceMismatchToleranceMin": 0.0,
            "priceMismatchToleranceMax": 0.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "grFF": null
    }ingCollab04":null,"flexStringCollab05":null,"blockShipments":null,"earlyShipmentTolerance":0,"overShipmentTolerance":0.0,"priceMismatchToleranceMin":0.0,"priceMismatchTo
```

You can see last few fields are repeated in output even after the completion of JSOn List from the queue. I have not pasted the whole JSOn as problem is at the end only and my JSOn LISt is somehow contains more fields.
I want to eliminate this problem.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds wrong. How do you write your messages to the queue to begin with?

Comment: @SeanFeldman I am sending the message into the Azure Service Queue. Using Brokered Message Class and using this line of code: service.sendQueueMessage("sq-jcibe-microservice-e2open-dev", message);

Comment: And BrokeredMessage is constructed using valid JSON? If that's the case, I suggest open an issue against this repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java